# Removing chars until a numeric is found from array item Bash

Tags: bash

I have the line of text within a text file. The line looks something like this:

```
xxxx,xxxxx,xxxxxx,xxxxx,xxxx,NL-1111 xx,xxxx,xxx
```

The NL- is an identifier for the country so this could be anything. I would like to remove the NL- part from the line so it looks like this:

```
xxxx,xxxxx,xxxxxx,xxxxx,xxxx,1111 xx,xxxx,xxx
```

And write the file afterwards.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you try anything?

Comment: @ChrisMaes  Yes, i played with sed and awk but i'm not sure what methods to use. I dont work with bash that often

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution close to `sed`'s ones, but with perl:

```
perl -i -pe "s/(?<=,)[a-zA-Z]{2}-//g" file.txt
```

It uses look behind expression, so that you don't need to repeat the comma in the replacement part.

Comment: This is a good solution, +1. It works on all platforms, unlike sed-in-place (`sed -i`); see my answer for details.

Comment: @bgoldst There is also some differences between platforms with perl `-i`: on some (on my Windows cmd for example), you need to specify a backup pattern after `-i` (no backup is not possible). With that, it works everywhere, but you get a backup file.

Answer (score 2):

I think the simplest solution here is reading it from the file into a shell variable, then writing it back immediately and using the pattern substitution variation of parameter expansion:

```
line="$(<file)"; echo "${line/[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]-}" >|file;
```

I would warn you against solutions that use sed-in-place functionality. I've found that sed behavior differs on different platforms with respect to the -i option. On Mac you have to give an empty argument (`''`) to the -i option, while on Cygwin you must *not* have an empty argument following the -i. To get platform compatibility you'd have to test what platform you're on.

Comment: not sure this will work since there is 'XXX,XXX,...' on the same line before NL-

Comment: It works. The dash at the end of the pattern protects the rest of the string.

Comment: Won't work if you have a prefix with more than 2 characters: it deletes only the last two characters plus the dash. Instead the prefix should be untouched.

Comment: The prefix is only two characters. Probably ISO 3166-1 alpha-2.

Answer (score 2):

something like this using sed

```
sed -i 's/,[A-Z][A-Z]-\([0-9]\+,\)/,\1/i' file.txt
```

`,[A-Z][A-Z]-\([0-9]\+,\)`search for comma letter, letter, `-`, digit(s), comma

`,\1`keep only the commas and the digits.

`i`ignore case on the letters

thankyou to @chris for proof-reading.

Comment: better solution with regex. is the `<` necessary?

Answer (score 1):

sed might do the trick: remove the string ",NL-", "BE-" etc from anywhere in the file:

```
sed -i 's/,[A-Z][A-Z]-/,/' file.txt
```

Comment: Yes, This works if the NL- part would be static. The problem is that this could be anything. NL-,BE-,DE- ect.

Comment: You should not remove the comma I think.

Comment: thanks for the comments; I adapted it slightly so it won't remove the comma, and will remove other countries as well... The regex by @Jasen might be better...